# Converting JSON to Java Class using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

I'm having some problems with deserializing a JSON object to a Java Class object, the JSON objects contain many invalid characters like "-" and "," that cannot be variable names in Java.
example:

```
{
     "Sugar, Total": 100,
     "Vitamin-A": 50,
}
```

I also have a class with private variables
example:

```
public class Food {
    private int sugarTotal;
    private int vitaminA;

    //Getters and Setters
}
```

now as I understand it GSON only fills in the variables with 100% matching names, I cant make the names that are given to me in the JSON object.
does anyone know how to solve my predicament.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class GSonFieldMapping
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "{\"Sugar, Total\": 100, \"Vitamin-A\": 50}";

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        Food food = gson.fromJson(s, Food.class);

        System.out.println(food);
    }

}

class Food
{
    @SerializedName(value = "Sugar, Total")
    private int sugarTotal;
    @SerializedName(value = "Vitamin-A")
    private int vitaminA;
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Food [sugarTotal=" + sugarTotal + ", vitaminA=" + vitaminA + "]";
    }

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

Comment: @JsonProperty is for Jackson is suppose.

Comment: is there any reason for using
@SerializedName(value = "Sugar, Total")
rather than
@SerializedName("Sugar, Total")
or is it just for style points?

Comment: @SerializedName has only one field, value. So both approaches are valid.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to use `@SerializedName('')` to let Gson know where to map the data like so:

```
public class Food {
    @SerializedName("Sugar, Total")
    private int sugarTotal;

    @SerializedName("Vitamin-A")
    private int vitaminA;
}
```